# Magento2 Auto Increment SKU

Tags: magento2, sku

I am willing to get product **SKU** value to auto-increment in **Magento 2**. For example the last product created sku was 100001 then the next product would be 100002 and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Till now Magento does not have such functionality. Though Magento provides the feature to set the mask for autogenerating SKU field.

To do so, go to

> Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Product Fields Auto-Generation

and set value of **Mask for SKU** field.

If you still want to auto-generate SKU field like 100001, 100002 etc., then you need to **create a custom module which will observe the event of product edit form load**. On this event, check whether it is an old product being edited or a new product is being created.

If a new product is being created, then you would need to get last SKU from the table and fill the value of SKU with **(last SKU + 1)** value.

**Note: Before doing above exercise, you would need to make two changes for SKU attribute:**

- Change SKU data type to integer
- Make the SKU field read-only, so that admin cannot change the generated value

Please check and let me know if you have any question.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this module on github which seems to be exactly what you're looking for

https://github.com/rakeshmagento/magento2-auto-sku-generator

**From the Link:** 
magento2 auto generate sku for new product based on custom confgiuration. Auto SKU Generator Addon provides the functionality of generating the SKU automatically

**Examples**
1 : Prefix -> D, Start From -> 1, SKU Length -> 5
D00001, D0002, D0003 ,........

3 : Prefix -> SKU, Start From -> 1, SKU Length -> 7
SKU0001, SKU0002, SKU0003, SKU0004 ,....................

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/117595)

Comment: I've added more info.